# How to get JSON data from a REST service

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, service

Hi am using restfull service and passing JSON data using jquery.
I am able to hit the URL, How can I get the JSON data which I passed from JQuery in the method.

My Rest Service is

```
        [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "InsertIntoDB/{jsonString}")]
    string InsertIntoDB( string jsonString);
```

I am calling above service as:

```
url = "http://localhost:54552/OfflineService.svc/InsertIntoDB/SomeRandomString";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(EmployeeData),
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processData: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success..." + data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    );
```

EmployeeData is an array containing employee Data,
 I am able to hit the service but I want to know how can I get the EmployeeData.

Comment: Use json_decode() to get the EmployeeData. json_decode is function of PHP. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
$employee_data = json_decode({your_json_string}, true);

Comment: in C# USE JsonConvert.DeserializeObject.

List<EmployeeData> emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmployeeData>>(json);
Console.WriteLine(emp.Count);


http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingCollections.htm